# reading file through scanner device in java

Tags: java

how can i read file of any type using scanner hardware device in java

Comment: Scanners don't read files. The scan images from paper (usually). What exactly do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at JTwain: http://asprise.com/product/jtwain/faq.php

They provide the following example code snippet:

```
try {

    Source source = SourceManager.instance().getDefaultSource(); // Acquire image from default source
    source.open();

    Image image = source.acquireImage(); // Acquire the image

    // Loads the image completely ...
    // Click here to find how to load images completely with MediaTracker.
    // ...

    int imageWidth = image.getWidth(this);
    int imageHeight = image.getHeight(this);

    BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(imageWidth, imageHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    Graphics2D g2 = bufferedImage.createGraphics();
    g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);

    // Now, you can use the bufferedImage object ...

}catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}finally{
    SourceManager.closeSourceManager();
}
```

Comment: thnks for providing solution,now how can i open this scanned file(which i have scan thru scanner) in browser using applets? how bufferedImage object is used in applet

Comment: You could use an `ImageIcon` and a `JLabel`.

Comment: is it FREE jTwain?

Comment: Have you checked [their webpage](http://asprise.com/product/jtwain/index.php)? It seems like the software is about to be retired.